# Why does grouping function work slow when fitting lm models

Tags: r, function, memory, group-by

I have data frame with 5 column and about 12 000 000 rows.

```
          lon   lat       for_R_WDEP_SOX number year
2        -29.95 30.05      128.44461      1 2000
624002   -29.95 30.05      320.17755      1 2001
1248002  -29.95 30.05      192.20628      1 2002
1872002  -29.95 30.05      325.44336      1 2003
2496002  -29.95 30.05      368.46976      1 2004
3120002  -29.95 30.05      409.80154      1 2005
3744002  -29.95 30.05      265.71161      1 2006
4368002  -29.95 30.05      147.92351      1 2007
4992002  -29.95 30.05      279.87851      1 2008
5616002  -29.95 30.05      136.38370      1 2009
6240002  -29.95 30.05      223.43958      1 2010
6864002  -29.95 30.05      132.92253      1 2011
7488002  -29.95 30.05      112.68416      1 2012
8112002  -29.95 30.05       83.81801      1 2013
8736002  -29.95 30.05       80.33523      1 2014
9360002  -29.95 30.05       71.58231      1 2015
9984002  -29.95 30.05       91.07822      1 2016
10608002 -29.95 30.05       98.69281      1 2017
```

I try to use groping function to it

```
gromov_analise_fuction <- function(table)
{

    x <- table$year
    y <- table$for_R_WDEP_SOX
    line<- lm(y~x)


    p_value_coef <- summary(line)$coefficients["x","Estimate"]/abs(summary(line)$coefficients["x","Estimate"])*(1 -summary(line)$coefficients["x","Pr(>|t|)"])

    k <- summary(line)$coefficients["x","Estimate"]
    B_K <- summary(line)$coefficients["x","Estimate"]*1800/summary(line)$coefficients["(Intercept)","Estimate"]
    result_vector <- c(p_value_coef,k,B_K)

    return (result_vector)     
}




result <- table %>%
        group_by(number) %>% 
        do(data.frame(val=gromov_analise_fuction(.)))
```

It works for about 30-37 minutes. 
Tell me please what is the reason? 
How should I make this code work faster.

As I understood I should remove unused vectors and data.frame.

Comment: Looks like you are fitting almost a million regression models ...

Comment: Assuming, you always have the same years, it might be possible to speed this up significantly by reshaping the data and utilizing that `lm` accepts a matrix on the LHS of the formula. But I'm not sure for such big data. Create a reproducible example if you need further help.

Comment: yes, you are right. I am fitting  about 600 000 models.

Comment: Yes, the years are the same. Data consits of 1200*500 points for 18 years. I should make from data frame to matrix,shouldn't I?

Comment: You might want to give a try with `data.table`, should be much faster than `dplyr`.

Comment: A model like `lm(cbind(y1, y2, ...) ~ x, data = ...)` needs to do the computationally intensive step of OLS only once. So, in principle just reshape your data to wide format and use such a model. However, I have never tested with this many dependent variables.

Comment: I should make wide table,shouldn't I?

Comment: And what will be function to this data?

Comment: Let me quote myself: "Create a reproducible example if you need further help."

Comment: I don't know how much computational burden it adds, and it's probably not your main problem, but `summary.lm()` does not-entirely-trivial computations -- you probably want to call `summary()` once, rather than 6(?) times ...

Comment: We live in a pretty amazing world: (37 min*60 sec/min)/600000 = 0.0037 seconds/regression. (I don't blame you for wanting to speed it up, but we should stop and appreciate this for a second ...)

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)

result2 <- table[,
                 data.frame(val=gromov_analise_fuction(.SD)),
                 by = number]
```

See how much faster `data.table` is! (BTW, check Hadley Wickham's GitHub repo, he has been re-writing dplyr verbs with the data.table backend to make these faster.)

```
Unit: nanoseconds
       expr     min      lq       mean  median        uq      max neval cld
      dplyr 3717853 4262732 5028474.44 4526830 5648242.0 15919477   100   b
 data.table      35      39     316.29      41     603.5     3024   100  a
```

And here are the outputs from your code with `dplyr` and the `data.table` way (with the data you provided in your question, I agree with @Roland though when it comes to providing data!):

```
> result (dplyr)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   number [1]
  number     val
   <int>   <dbl>
1      1  -0.998
2      1 -13.9  
3      1  -0.890

> result2 (data.table)
   number         val
1:      1  -0.9979470
2:      1 -13.8587730
3:      1  -0.8900289
```

Comment: when I used data_analyse (the last data frame) with such code `result2 <- table[,
                 data.frame(val=gromov_analise_fuction(.SD)),
                 by = number]` It tells me error

Comment: `SD` means "subset of data", that is data.table jargon, check some of their tutorials. And regarding your error, you need to let us know what the error is so we can help!

Comment: I went to tutorial, and understood how data.table works. Perhaps data.table is calculating my data for 25 minutes and still didn't finish.

Comment: Then I would focus on optimizing your function, `gromov_analise_function()` as @Roland and @Ben Bolker suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

You can speed up fitting the models significantly, but the slow part is calculating the model summaries. The "low-hanging fruit" is limiting the calls to summary to one call per model, obviously. You might want to create your own function that calculates only the values of interest, i.e., the p-values for the slopes (see [there](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/44838/11849) for the calculation of the standard errors). For the coefficients you can just use the function `coef` which is fast.

Here is an approach that fits the models much faster (but still uses `summary`):

```
library(data.table)
n <- 1e5
set.seed(42)
DT <- data.table(x = 1:10, y = rnorm(n), g = rep(seq_len(n/10), each = 10))

#fit each model separately
system.time({
  res <- DT[, .(pslope = summary(lm(y ~ x, data = .SD))$coefficients["x","Pr(>|t|)"]), by = g]
})    
#user  system elapsed 
#5.89    0.01    6.02

#use the fact that the models have all the same design matrix
system.time({
  DT1 <- dcast(DT, x ~ g, value.var = "y")
  setnames(DT1, make.names(names(DT1)))
  fit <- lm(as.formula(sprintf("cbind(%s) ~ x", paste(names(DT1)[-1], collapse = ","))), data = DT1)
  pslope <- vapply(summary(fit), function(fitsum) fitsum$coefficients["x","Pr(>|t|)"], FUN.VALUE = 1.0)
})
#user  system elapsed 
#4.34    0.00    4.42

#same result
all.equal(unname(pslope), res[["pslope"]])
#[1] TRUE

#intercepts
coef(fit)[1,]
#slopes
coef(fit)[2,]
```